# Infer function argument type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to automatically infer function argument types as follows:

```js
const FUNCTION_A = "a";
const FUNCTION_B = "b";

type FunctionKeyType = typeof FUNCTION_A | typeof FUNCTION_B;

function functionA(arg: string): string {
    return "A";
}

function functionB(arg: number): string {
    return "B";
}

type AnyFunctionType = (arg: any) => string;

const funcs: Record<FunctionKeyType, AnyFunctionType> = {
    [FUNCTION_A]: functionA,
    [FUNCTION_B]: functionB
}

console.log("A:", funcs[FUNCTION_A]("a")) // works
console.log("B:", funcs[FUNCTION_B](0))  // works
console.log("B:", funcs[FUNCTION_B]("fail")) // should fail typechecking but does not
```

- There will be a large number of `functions` with unique `arg` types, but each will always have a single argument called `arg` and return a `string`
- I need to have a mechanism for `key` => `function`, however it doesn't necessarily need to be a `Record`

Is there a way to write `AnyFunctionType` such that when I use a function via `funcs["..."]`, it infers the type of the argument?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYgVQHIGEAqBJA8kg+gQRgF4YAiAQ1IG4BYAKFElkVUx1wCFiyAja++lACeABwCm8AK5hgUAJbgA0mKFpREksPEgAZvGTpseQgB8YWsbv2sjnWnXo7pshWBhOZ88PgAU5AE4A5gBcMND+cmCBAJSh4ZGBMADe9ACQ-mJQkv5upPj8dAC+AnQeLuDuzl5gHH5BoWCSALY8Yv6xYVARUclpGVk5ZBwFxQ50FjD4YEJwVa5q4tx1ITDk09HEAHyd3YH29IzQlTIQoQBKYqD+ACYAPLOersqq6gA0k9MP5WALYtskKToqQA2ixDOx8ABdUJlar4V5pUEGNh4DjQ47fDj0UYHcAQEAAGzEADoCSBAj48sFSO8yhAkTYIZDKZRohsAPTsmAAdxA-gA1hBcZBCSSyRTSBxqbTnPSwSjOMyAAxsmAwTk8vmC4X4omk8mUqU0jFy5G2NGUnTkOQE0iqjUQAAWIEkBOu7mtBPM6mAjsu-ISMB4klg1xAYggMDAICgQA)

Comment: Will the calls to the functions be hardcoded like that? `funcs["a"]("a")`? Or will the key be a plain string?

Comment: It will use typed string literals for keys as well as for accessing the functions (Edited post to reflect key types)

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the type as `Record<string, AnyFunctionType>` then all functions are assumed to be of type `AnyFunctionType` which takes `any` as an argument.

If you want to apply a constraint, but infer something more specific than that, then you need to use a generic function to make this object. (See [issue#47920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920) for how this might be solved in the future)

```
function makeFuncs<T extends Record<string, AnyFunctionType>>(funcs: T) {
    return funcs
}

const funcs = makeFuncs({
    "a": functionA,
    "b": functionB
})

const badFuncs = makeFuncs({
    "a": functionA,
    "b": functionB
})

console.log("A:", funcs["a"]("a")) // works
console.log("B:", funcs["b"](0))  // works
console.log("B:", funcs["b"]("fail")) // error
```

And it enforces that the the function signature is correct:

```
const badFuncs = makeFuncs({
    "a": functionA,
    "b": () => 123 // type error
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=3&pln=25&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSsEEEAUBDATgcwC5EBnKXGMfASmLIqsQG8BYAKAEhcBTKEXJACJ0ggNzsAvu3Ypo8JLLRgAQjgLEwIALYAjbrlqlylfM3Zde-IcrGTpbKAE8ADt0TowjgGLg5CACoubgC8iGpEiNie1IjBAHxGDPjibDK+Soha2ADW3D6QJAA8-ojcAB5Q3GAAJiSIAErcEHC41YX0JgA07p75fmCBrnFxmLIkxP4xrJw8fALIviR2qWzNYGQLBbGZOXmLmNMcgtiCxIry6J3siEc6p5v9ypLU9mskcAA23AB0H3D4mGEhEE3TGAG1joIALqAk7UGIAegRiAA7i1sktVgh3l9fv9AcpgaDFhC7jCAAzwxCIJGo9GYt6fH5-AGCQkgh4kUnQwHAbAwD6CKm0kgACzgIA+1WQ-I+iCcrggoqa2RM9nYbygiB02GqfTqoSyuX1B3MkLO6QuVzYN0Ed2ImBi8UQAEYAEwAZhpyIVbn0uBazyAA)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a Generic Function to implement this constraint.

```
type AnyFunctionType = (arg: any) => string;


function InferFunctionType<T extends {[k: string]:  AnyFunctionType }>(t: T){
    return t
}

const funcs =  InferFunctionType({
    "a": functionA,
    "b": functionB, 
})



console.log("A:", funcs["a"]("a")) // works
console.log("B:", funcs["b"](0))  // works
console.log("B:", funcs["b"]("fail")) // Here Typechecking gives error
```

[Code Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSsEEEAUBDATgcwC5EBnKXGMfASmLIqsQG8BYAKAEhcBTKEXJACJ0ggNzsAvu3Ypo8JLLRgAQjgLEwIALYAjbrlqlylfM3Zde-IcrGTpbKAE8ADt0TowjgGLg5CACoubgC8iGpEiNie1IjBAHxGDPjibPaK8ogAkmDA%20j6o8oGuADz%20iNwAHlDcYAAmJMwA2gDWdMZUALrE7p75fmBFbhJxmFDE-tSsnDx8AohQdqlsEAhkyL4NoVk5eb5Kg5hTHILYgsTpGAA07IiIxzpn6wUIypeIktT27CtgJHAANtwAHT-OD4TDCQiCN6yEiNE6CDoQ07UGIAejRiAA7nBcM0SN9VgDgaDwYJlFCYRt4Q8kQAGVG3DHY3H4wm-YkgsEQinQp4QOGCWkQ4DYGD-QSM5kACX0bkGEAAFtwIM0TIh8DAAG7cBr6XC49hAA)

Answer (score 0):

You've said the calls will be as shown, where the function name is a compile-time constant. That's good news! That means you can do it. :-) You can have a compile-time constant object to do the lookup on:

```typescript
const funcs = {
    "a": functionA,
    "b": functionB
} as const; // <== Note

console.log("A:", funcs["a"]("a"));         // Works
console.log("B:", funcs["b"](0));           // Works
console.log("A wrong:", funcs["a"](0));     // Error as desired
console.log("B wrong:", funcs["b"]("x"));   // Error as desired
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSsEEEAUBDATgcwC5EBnKXGMfASmLIqsQG8BYAKEU8VwFMoRcSAETohAbnYBfduxTR4SOWjAAhHAWJgQAWwBGPXLVLlK+Zuy7c+A4SvFSZbCAjLJwEEogC85jlyHYQsRKCugANBb+ukFuqAoqUojYns5gZBJs7KkkcAA2PAB0uXD4mCKEQmGxHgDaAUIAumWB1NRilh0A9J2IAOpwuADWJFkueYXFpUIqFVVyJHXRTQAMre0dXT39QyNOY-lFJWXoiADuuAhEldUL9Strm4gAorgXuEmeACY8JDC8n6M0uNDlMVGcLlRZjdFo0ygAPIQPTjdZ6vAYfRDfX7-dhAA)

You get full IDE support there as well, the intellisense tells you the argument type required.

Comment: @t-j-crowder, but this won't stop us from assigning anything to funcs right?
like `const funcs = { a: () => Array<[]>, b: boolean  } as const `  because nothing is constraining us from doing that, which is required in the problem statement I guess

Comment: @Bishwajitjha - Yes, it won't. No, I don't think that's required by the problem statement. :-) But it's up to the OP (and others using our answers) to decide for themselves what's appropriate for them.